# Identifying Registered Users That Have Never Made a Purchase

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1, reports, register

When someone registers on a Magento Enterprise site (v 1.13), where is that information stored? It *could* be under "Newsletter Subscribers" or "Customers", but that list wouldn't necessarily include everyone, correct? I'm trying to create a **list of people that have registered but have never made a purchase.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a [free module available that includes a similar report](https://github.com/digitalpianism/customreports)

The difference is it only lists the people who subscribed to the newsletter and never purchased.

I guess you can use it as a starting point.

To retrieve such collection I'm using the following code:

```
    // Get the customer emails
    $orderEmailsCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email');

    // Call iterator walk method with collection query string and callback method as parameters
    // Has to be used to handle massive collection instead of foreach
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($orderEmailsCollection->getSelect(), array(array($this, 'fillArray')));

    $collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect(array('subscriber_id','subscriber_email','subscriber_status'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_email',array('nin'=>$this->filterOrdersEmails));
```

Note that the `fillArray` callback method is simply a method to fill a protected array with the customer emails:

```
$this->filterOrdersEmails[] = $args['row']['customer_email'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will your module will work on Enterprise 1.13?

Do you know if all people that use the registration form  get added as a customer?

Comment: @Realto619 never tried to be honest. Give it a try and contact me if you face issues, I'll be willing to fix any issues on this version ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one off process, it might be easiest to simply use a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    user.entity_id, user.email
FROM customer_entity AS user
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS ord
    ON ord.customer_id = user.entity_id
WHERE ord.entity_id IS NULL
GROUP BY user.entity_id;
```